# What if you don't hit Sans at the end of the fight?

Tags: undertale

Before anybody says I could try it myself, I played it but can't get Sans to tire out so I can't try out this question myself because his fight is too hard for me.

What if, when Sans is tired for his "special attack", you choose the hit button but then instead of hitting him, you let the bar slide across the entire thing causing it to miss? I couldn't find any videos or pictures of this, so is it possible to do that or would you hit him anyway? If you can miss him intentionally then what happens after?

Comment: Looks like the video here has your answer but I'm uncertain if this is the occasion you're looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnNjVTa6m3s. Basically the fight doesn't progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to finally beat Sans, and learned that it is impossible to miss if you push the box down to the "fight" button and hit him, it doesn't make the normal hit bar appear and it just automatically hits, so once you get to that point that's litterally the end. There is no way to miss.

TL:DR; I beat Sans (albeit after 50 tries), and tried it myself. It automatically hits him so the fight ends there. You can't miss or continue.

Comment: Put this answer here for anybody who may have seen this and been wondering too.

Comment: I had the same feeling that you didn't get the normal bar after pressing the "fight" box